# TValueListEditor - how to validate input?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I have a TValueListEditor and want to validate input. For example replace all spaces to underscores.

How to do that? I thought OnSetEditText might be good but I can't change Value there.

Comment: Try `OnValidate()`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thank you. Almost. I want something to validate instantly and OnValidate validates after the field looses focus.

Comment: Well, not exactly, but still not what you expect: "...of the cell that is about to lose focus*. There no check while user is typing. If you need that, then you need to write your own check.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me

```
procedure TForm1.ValueListEditor1GetEditText(Sender: TObject; ACol,
  ARow: Integer; var Value: string);
begin
  CurrentRow := ARow;
end;

procedure TForm1.ValueListEditor1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if CurrentRow <> 3 then Exit;

  if Key = 32 then Key := 0;
end;
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question - please use this website as it is intended to.

Comment: @AmigoJack How can this not be an answer? It validates in real time.

Comment: It manipulates, not validates. On top you forget mouse actions like rightclick > paste/cut.